# Cannot install app on device 9.3.2 from Xcode 7.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I accidentally installed iOS 9.3.2 on my development iPhone 6s device and now Xcode fail to install the app on the device (it still working on the simulator).

[image]

This iOS update has been installed automatically last night and I don't have any recent backup.
Anyone with the same problem?

Comment: I think you need to update xcode to the latest version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem as well, and tried everything. Regenerating all my certificates. Clearing my certificates on the keychain. Regenerating my provisioning profiles and nothing worked.

I then simply did Product > Clean and then deleted derived data and it worked!

Xcode must be keeping some cache of the certificates id's or something.

Answer (score 2):

If Himanshu's solution doesnt work, then you must update Xcode version

Answer (score 1):

from project navigator select your project under targets and check deployment target!!

Check maximum deployment target.

for example, In my case maximum is `9.2`.

[image]

If it is less then `9.3.2`, I mean less then your device's iOS version, then you need to upgrade xcode which support this iOS version. If it is greater then it (9.3.2) then problem should be different.

you should once try by clean the project. You can clean project by (cmd + shift + k) .

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just had to unplug the device from the USB port and plug it back in.

One thing to note is that the battery was flat and at the time I first tried to run my app on the device the battery was at 2% and not correctly read by Xcode/Devices. Once it went above 10% it was running again.