# I am getting an error message when I try to run a Xcode project on my phone?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am getting this message when I try to run Xcode project in my iPhone:

```
“(null)” is of a model that is not supported by this version of Xcode.
Please use a different device.
```

Xcode version is 7.3.1，my iPhone is is running iOS9.3.2

Comment: Trying updating to Xcode version 7.3.2

Comment: Where is 7.3.2 I cant find it.

Comment: Restarting Xcode fixed it for me. Why did this happen? Not sure, but I noticed my device had started downloading iOS 10. The download had not finished and the update had not started, my device was still on iOS 9.3.1, but I got this message.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Simply restart your Xcode and plug your phone off and on again.

Answer (score 23):

Restarting only XCode work for me, No need to unplug the iPhone.

Answer (score 5):

You could try the following, let me know if none of these work, good luck.

1. Use a different USB port
2. [Cannot install app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37524575/cannot-install-app-on-device-9-3-2-from-xcode-7-3-1), has some options which might help

Answer (score 4):

Reattaching the device and restarting XCode worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

For me, using a different USB cable was the solution. Restarting Xcode or unplugging/replugging cable did not work. I used a very old cable in the beginning, iPhone was charging but Xcode was not happy with the cable, giving this error.

Sometimes, if it is also first time using iPhone with the Macbook, Xcode doesn't see the iPhone. Unplugging and replugging does the work then.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add my 'weird' situation. Usually, I have my iPhone plugged directly into my MacBook. This time, however, I had it plugged in the Apple's keyboard which was connected to the laptop.

Plugging the iPhone into the laptop directly resolved the issue. In my case, I had to restart XCode too.

There, hope this will help someone with this kind of issue.

Answer (score 1):

Follow those steps:

1. Unplug your iPhone via disconnecting the datacable
2. Restart your Xcode.
3. Connect again & run.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a broken USB cable. Device was shown in XCode but deployment didn't work.